# How to run a Websocket Server in Odoo 14?

Tags: websocket, odoo, odoo-14

I would like to find a way to run a Websocket server in Odoo 14.

I need it to connect with my devices that only use Websocket as its only protocol for communication.

I tried some Websocket libraries but the result is that when it runs, it interrupts the main Odoo service, which is not what I want.

I want to have both Odoo service and Websocket server running and listening to its own things separately inside Odoo.

Is there a way to achieve such task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run a third application to communicate odoo and your device.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am currently doing. I am running `nodejs` with `expressjs` and `ws` for this, and it is working as intended. However, I would love to have a more direct way by by-passing the third application altogether.